# .send_keys(Keys.RETURN) - python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Not sure if I'm in the right section here,But I need a little help trying to make my code do a keyboard "ENTER"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.adidas.com/us')
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/input[1]')
searchbox.send_keys('NMD_R1 SHOES').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should:

```
searchbox.send_keys('NMD_R1 SHOES' + Keys.ENTER)
```

I suggest to locate `searchbox` use `.find_element_by_name('q')`, although your way also works.

Finally:

```
searchbox = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
searchbox.send_keys('NMD_R1 SHOES' + Keys.ENTER)
```